# "Refundable amount" vs "Amount to be refunded"

Tags: terminology

Is it possible to use "refundable" where I mean "to be refunded"? I know that "payable amount" has a meaning of "amount to be payed". Is it the same with refund? I need very short term, preferable one word, used as an API field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can say "**refundable amount**" - *an amount that can be returned (or is returned)*. Consider "**[refund](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refund)**" - *an amount of money that is given back to you, especially because you are not happy with a product or service that you have bought*.

Consider this:

> The term **refundable deposits** refers to cash collected from credit customers that a company expects to return after a specified period of time, or when certain conditions are satisfied. When companies collect this money, the intention is to return it after a relatively brief period of time.

Answer (score 4):

Whether they can be used interchangeably would depend on the context.  In most everyday matters, they are synonymous. But in certain legal contexts, for example, there could be a difference in meaning.

**refundable** = *can* be refunded (i.e. circumstances permit or allow)
**to be refunded** =  *will* be refunded

There could also be a difference if the refund process consisted of several stages, an initial approval stage:

```
Amount Refundable
Refund Approved Date
```

a secondary stage where the refund amount can be allocated in different ways:

```
Refund Amount To Be Applied to Current Tax Year
Amount To Be Refunded to Taxpayer
```

and a stage where the monies were transferred:

```
Amount Refunded
Transaction Date
```

This is just an example to show the potential difference in meaning between the adjective with the **able** ending and **to be** + {past participle}.